# Device orientation settings not effecting iPad devices

Tags: ios, xcode

Why is it that iPads are not effected when un-ticking the device orientation check boxes? Could it be that I'm using the simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `info.plist` file you need to add `Supported interface orientations (iPad)` to specify iPad orientations.

Options are
`Portrait (bottom home button)` `Portrait (top home button)` `Landscape (left home button)` `Landscape (right home button)`

The `deployment info` section in Targets only shows iPhone orientations for *Universal* app targets... bit dumb on Apple's part, but there you go!